# Hibernate MySQL 5.6 auto reconnect after timeout in Spring app

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am using hibernate 4.3.8 to connect to my MySQL 5.6 db.  After awhile, my connection times out, so that the next time a db call is made, a "java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out" error is thrown.  How can I have hibernate automatically reconnect to the db?  This is what the data source and hibernate section of my beans file looks like:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://url:3306/db" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="username />
    <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>Class1</beans:value>
            <beans:value>Class2</beans:value>
                          .
                          .
                          .
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

In older versions of MySQL, I know you could just add "?autoReconnect=true " to the db url, but that has since been deprecated.  I do not want to change the dataSource or use c3p0 for my connection pool if I can avoid it.  Not sure if this helps, but the mysql-connector-java version is 5.1.6. I believe I need to add some properties to the hibernate properties section, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this in your hibernate config file

```
<property name="connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
<property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
<property name="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</property>
```